# How to make the table in class elsarticle, which is two column wide?

Tags: tables, elsarticle

I am using document class elsarticle for drawing a table which should be both columns wide like  [image: this]    But my table is not going as wide, also how to shift table caption to left like shown in this figure. plz, guide. I am using the following code.

```
\documentclass[final, 5p, times, twocolumn]{elsarticle}
    %\documentclass[times]{elsarticle}
    \journal{Nuclear Physics B}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[h] 
        \caption{Confusion Matrix for EmoDB Datset}       
            
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c cc}
            
            \hline
            &angry&boredom&disgust&fear&happy&sadness&neutral\\
            \hline
            angry&\textbf{0.96}&0.00&0.00&0.01&0.03&0.00&0.00\\
            boredom&0.00&\textbf{0.92}&0.00&0.01&0.00&0.02&0.05\\
            disgust&0.00&0.00&\textbf{100}&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00\\
            fear&0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{0.93}&0.02&0.00&0.05\\
            happy&0.08&0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{0.90}&0.00&0.02\\
            sadness&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{100}&0.00\\
            neutral&0.00&0.06&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.03&\textbf{0.91}\\
            \hline              
            
        \end{tabular}       
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: This] is what I am getting.

Comment: That seems to be the correct width of your `tabular`, isn't it? You might want to place a `\centering` directly after `\begin{table*}` so that all its contents are centred, not just the caption.

Comment: If you want a wider table you could use a package like `tabularx` and it's `X` type columns, but I don't think this is a particularly good idea here, tables with that much white space are just harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you're interested in stretching the table from its natural width, that it currently has, to the entire linewidth. For this you could use `tabular*` in combination with `\extracolsep{\fill}}`. Since the table then contains a huge amount of wastes white space which does not really make the table more readable, I included an alternative layout that easily fits into one of the two document columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[final, 5p, times, twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[times]{elsarticle}
\journal{Nuclear Physics B}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating, makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text using the \lipsum command, do not use in real document.
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{table*}[h] 
    \caption{Confusion Matrix for EmoDB Datset}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c c c cc}
        \toprule
        &angry&boredom&disgust&fear&happy&sadness&neutral\\
        \midrule
        angry&\textbf{0.96}&0.00&0.00&0.01&0.03&0.00&0.00\\
        boredom&0.00&\textbf{0.92}&0.00&0.01&0.00&0.02&0.05\\
        disgust&0.00&0.00&\textbf{100}&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00\\
        fear&0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{0.93}&0.02&0.00&0.05\\
        happy&0.08&0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{0.90}&0.00&0.02\\
        sadness&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{100}&0.00\\
        neutral&0.00&0.06&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.03&\textbf{0.91}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\begin{table}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont boredom}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \caption{Confusion Matrix for EmoDB Datset}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l c c c c c cc@{}}
        \toprule
        &\rothead{angry} &\rothead{boredom} & \rothead{disgust} & \rothead{fear} & \rothead{happy} & \rothead{sadness} & \rothead{neutral}\\
        \midrule
        angry   & \textbf{0.96}&0.00&0.00&0.01&0.03&0.00&0.00\\
        boredom & 0.00&\textbf{0.92}&0.00&0.01&0.00&0.02&0.05\\
        disgust & 0.00&0.00&\textbf{100}&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00\\
        fear    & 0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{0.93}&0.02&0.00&0.05\\
        happy   & 0.08&0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{0.90}&0.00&0.02\\
        sadness & 0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&\textbf{100}&0.00\\
        neutral & 0.00&0.06&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.03&\textbf{0.91}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Just one question how can I shift the caption to the left as I mentioned in the question figure. regards